# SQLite "LIKE" syntax didn't bring any results

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I try to read from the sqliteDB with the following query:

```
public ArrayList<ReminderNote> getAllRegexItems(String author) {
 ArrayList<ReminderNote> results = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor cursor = this.getReadableDatabase().query(
            REMINDER_NOTE_TABLE,
            new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_NOTE, KEY_AUTHOR}, Strings.isEmpty(author) ? null : KEY_AUTHOR + " = ?",
            Strings.isEmpty(author) ? null : new String[]{"%" + author + "%"}, null, null, null);
```

Is it OK to use the `%` like I did?

If author is null or empty I want all the results to be fetched.

Unfortunately I get empty results set even though I added such entity beforehand.

And I can see non-empty results set when I execute:

```
Cursor cursor = this.getReadableDatabase().query(
            REMINDER_NOTE_TABLE,
            new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_NOTE, KEY_AUTHOR}, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Where is the "like" syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `KEY_AUTHOR + " = ?"`, you should be using `KEY_AUTHOR + " LIKE ?"`

```
Cursor cursor = this.getReadableDatabase().query(
        REMINDER_NOTE_TABLE,
        new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_NOTE, KEY_AUTHOR},
        Strings.isEmpty(author) ? null : KEY_AUTHOR + " LIKE ?",
        Strings.isEmpty(author) ? null : new String[]{"%" + author + "%"},
        null, null, null);
```